# Why can static data members have incomplete type?

Tags: c++

Chapter 7.6 of the book C++ Primer says the following:

> As one example, a static data member can have incomplete type (§ 7.3.3, p. 278). In particular, a static data member can have the same type as the class type of which it is a member.

Is this because the static data member is only declared in the class definition and not defined?

Comment: static data members are mostly as global variables, (And it is legal to declare a global variable with incomplete type).

Comment: It is because static members don't need to be stored inside class's instances. Compiler doesn't need to know the size of static data members, in order to use your class instances

Comment: This is allowed because C++ standard allows it (section [class.static.data]). Are you asking what is the reasoning behind allowing this in the standard?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov how does the compiler know how to create a static data member of the same type as the class type of which it is a member when it doesn't know the type size?

Comment: @L.S.Roth, As an example: `struct S {static int m_ia[];}; int S::m_ia[7];`  consider `struct S` being in a header and `m_ia[7];` being in some specific translation unit (.cpp file).